# how to init noncopyable base class with runtime-choosing base-ctor

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic, constructor, initialization

can i destroy base class and recreate it in derived with this trick?

```
class base: noncopyable
{
    base();         //ctor with none param
    base(int x);    //ctor with one param
    base(int x, int y); //ctor with two param

    virtual ~base();
}

struct params
{
    int x;
    int y;
    enum 
    {
        typeNoneParam,  //neither x nor y is defined
        typeOneParam,   //only x is defined
        typeTwoParam    //x and y both are defined
    }typeParam;
}

class Derived
{
    Derived(params p);  //construct base class conditionally by p.typeParam
}

Derived::Derived(params p)
    :base() //default typeNoneParam
{
    //typeNoneParam need not do special process

    if (p.typeParam == params::typeOneParam)
    {
        base::~base();  //delete the default-typeNoneParam creation by base-dtor
        base(p.x);      //recreate the new base with one-param base-ctor
    }
    if (p.typeParam == params::typeOneParam)
    {
        base::~base();  //delete the default-typeNoneParam creation by base-dtor
        base(p.x, p.y); //recreate the new base with two-param base-ctor
    }
}
```

All declaration for class derived and base cannnot change, struct params cannnot either.

Only Implementation of derived class is changing-permitted.

can anyone give idea about is that implematation right? And any other more gentle implementation satisfy this scenario(init noncopyable base class with dynamically-choosing base-ctor) well?

Comment: The posted code wont compile, as you call the `base` constructor in the initializer list of `Derived`, but `Derived` does not actually inherit from `base`, nor does it contain a member variable of type `base`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Derived class constructor depends on a valid Base class object being constructed first. By destroying the Base class I'm almost positive you're flirting with Undefined Behavior. You might see this manifested with virtual functions for example.

The proper way to do this is for the Derived class to pass the parameters into the Base class constructor as part of the initialization list:

```
Derived(params p) : base(p) {};
```

Comment: yeah, but what if we cannot change base class?

Comment: @user1580722 then you should change `Derived` so that it takes more than just a single `params` so that you can choose the proper base constructor.  You're asking for more flexibility than C++ gives you.

Comment: And for the Undefined Behavior, could you give me more clues?Maybe some trick can bypass the dirty undefined behavior?

Comment: @user1580722, by definition undefined behavior is undefined and therefore somewhat unpredictable. If you can "think like a compiler" you might discern a likely outcome, but of course that is subject to change as the compiler version changes.

Comment: i accepted your first opinion, and changed base class, this is the best solution at least for now.

Answer (score 1):

I this case I would add a static factory function to your derived class (optionally make your constructors protected). You can put the switch on `typeParam` in there and create your object with the correct constructor. You will need to have three constructors in your derived class, one for each enum entry.

This will give the proper behaviour without hacks.